# Calculate/Convert the id field in the frontend

Tags: extjs

I am trying to calculate/convert the id in the frontend, but it is not done by ExtJS. Example:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'test',
    type: 'int'
}, {
    name: 'id',
    depends: [
        'test'
    ],
    convert: function(v, rec) {
        return rec.get('test')%10;
    }
}]
```

If I now load into the store five records with values for "test" being 1, 2, 3, 5, 11,

- the id should be the int calculated from the value of "test", and not autogenerated.
- the record with test=11 should have id=1 and thus overwrite the records with test=1 (also id=1)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gpp

However, this does not work as expected, the id is always auto-generated and thus, the deduplication does not work as expected.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the [mapping](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-mapping) method which receives the raw json data that you have configured using reader and you can do any type of preprocessing. whereas [calculate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate) and [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert) methods have restricted access to the data which needs to be defined in the fields prior to the usage.

```
fields: [{
    name: 'test',
    type: 'int'
}, {
    name: 'id',
    mapping(data){
        return data.test % 10;   
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, the `mapping` method worked. Didn't know you could put a method in there, I always assumed only strings were allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason of not working is [`idProperty`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty) model.

```
Defaults to:'id'
```

The [`depends`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-depends) config will work if you will change the `idProperty` in model or field name any other instead of `id`.

You can check this working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gq8)** with `depends` config. Hope this will help/guide you to solve your problem with `depends` config.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('ModelName', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty:'test',
            fields: [{
                name: 'test',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'id',
                depends: ['test'],
                convert: function(v, rec) {
                    return rec.get('test')%10;
                }
            }]
        });
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'ModelName',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        });
        store.on('load', function() {
            // Due to clashes between the calculated id,
            // the store should contain four records.
            console.log(store.getRange());
        });
        store.load();

        Ext.define('ModelName1', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'test',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: '_id',
                depends: ['test'],
                convert: function(v, rec) {
                    return rec.get('test')%10;
                }
            }]
        });
        var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'ModelName1',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        });
        store1.on('load', function() {
            // Due to clashes between the calculated id,
            // the store should contain four records.
            console.log(store1.getRange());
        });
        store1.load();
    }
});
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I have used `id` because I needed the specialty of the `idProperty`, namely, automated deduplication.